# How to add a from lookup field value to the text

Tags: 2010, development, lookup-column

I think about how to add a from lookup value to the text ? How can I write it to another colum ? In the same list.

Comment: Yes :), only Value from lookup field.

Comment: And how get a LookupField in Event Receiver ?

Comment: but why LookupListName_x003a_ID ? Why why wrait it pernamently ? :)

Comment: Post it as answer but please first in Your answer tell why we write it pernamently. I don't geret why we write here LookupListName_x003a_ID as pernamently value :)

Comment: In my example it should be "Procent_x003a_Identyfikator"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the ID column into the Child List from Lookup Fields... If you go to Site Settings -> Click lookup Column -> In section "Add a column to show each of these additional fields" check ID field!

Then in code you can access it like:

```
item["LookupListName_x003a_ID"]
```

Replace "LookupListName" with the Lookup List's name in your case!

**EXPLANATION:**
When you extend a column from Lookup field, the name of the field in your list becomes like: `LookupListName:FieldName` so if you extend ID field, the field name will be `LookupListName:ID`

Now when you access the fields in code, you need to use Internal Names and all the special characters are replaced by some code... code for ':' is '*x003a*', so when you try to access the field in code you will write:
`LookupListName_x003a_ID` instead of `LookupListName:ID`

You can see complete code conversions here:
[SharePoint Column/Field Display Names vs Internal Names](http://salaudeen.blogspot.com/2011/06/sharepoint-columnfield-display-names-vs.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
        SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("Your list");
        SPListItem item = list.GetItemByID(ID);
        SPFieldLookupValue fieldLookupValue = new SPFieldLookupValue(item["FieldName"].ToString());
        int lookupID = fieldLookupValue.LookupId;
        string lookupValue = fieldLookupValue.LookupValue;
        item["TextFieldName"] = lookupValue
```

If I have understood the question correctly...

Comment: And how get the fields in Event Receiver ?

Comment: public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            base.ItemUpdated(properties);
            SPListItem item = properties.ListItem;