# How to get Dependant LookUp Column Values in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: lookup-column

I am trying to get the Dependant Lookup column values in sharepoint 2010 but unable to get the value so how can we read the values from Dependant LookUp Column.

thanks in advance

Comment: What have you already tried? Did you tried accessing the field value via column name? Look [How to add a from lookup field value to the text](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/52566/how-to-add-a-from-lookup-field-value-to-the-text/52598)